# Fetch common elements from NSArray of dictionaries based on the value for key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries. Here's the array.

```
Month records (
    {
    BMI = "209.75";
    Date = "15/07/2014 09:03 AM";
    Height = 42;
    Weight = 37;
    day = 15;
    month = 7;
    year = 2014;
},
    {
    BMI = "366.67";
    Date = "21/07/2014 09:03 AM";
    Height = 30;
    Weight = 33;
    day = 21;
    month = 7;
    year = 2014;
},
    {
    BMI = "831.02";
    Date = "15/07/2014 09:04 AM";
    Height = 19;
    Weight = 30;
    day = 15;
    month = 7;
    year = 2014;
}
)
```

Now I want to fetch the elements of same "day" (as per here, there are 2 elements of "day=15" and 1 element of "day=7"). Then calculate the average BMI value for that particular day.

In general, my requirement is to fetch common elements(based on a value for key) and put them in a new array. What is the best way to do this at the runtime with a large data set.

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you looked at indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:, or filteredArrayUsingPredicate:?

Comment: Yes I tried filteredArrayUsingPredicate. Since the value for the key "day" which is the predicate is a dynamic one, I am struggling to define the predicate. I think you got my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int day = /* ... */;
NSArray* recordsForDay = [records filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"day == %d", day]];
```

or:

```
NSIndexSet* indexes = [record indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL (NSDictionar* record, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[record objectForKey:@"day"] intValue] == day;
}];
NSArray* recordsForDay = [records objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Comment: Since `day` is an int, you should probably change `@"day == %@"` to `@"day == %d"`, or maybe change `day` to `@(day)`.

Comment: @DrBeardface: Oops, you're right. I was thinking `%d` while my fingers went ahead and typed `%@`. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have discovered that this will be very hard to do with the current way you are storing the values.  If you can change how you are constructing the dictionaries, you could make it quite simple:

```
NSMutableArray *records = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];

NSDictionary *record = @{@"BMI":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:209.75],
                         @"Date":@"15/07/2014 09:03 AM",
                         @"Height":[NSNumber numberWithInt:42],
                         @"Weight":[NSNumber numberWithInt:37],
                         @"DayMonthYear":[NSNumber numberWithInt:20140715],
                         @"day":[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],
                         @"month":[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
                         @"year":[NSNumber numberWithInt:2014] };

[records addObject:record];


record = @{@"BMI": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:366.67],
           @"Date":@"21/07/2014 09:03 AM",
           @"Height":[NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
           @"Weight":[NSNumber numberWithInt:33],
           @"DayMonthYear":[NSNumber numberWithInt:20140721],
           @"day":[NSNumber numberWithInt:21],
           @"month":[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
           @"year":[NSNumber numberWithInt:2014] };

[records addObject:record];

record = @{@"BMI":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:831.02],
           @"Date":@"15/07/2014 09:04 AM",
           @"Height":[NSNumber numberWithInt:19],
           @"Weight":[NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
           @"DayMonthYear":[NSNumber numberWithInt:20140715],
           @"day":[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],
           @"month":[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
           @"year":[NSNumber numberWithInt:2014] };

[records addObject:record];
```

Now that we have set up the dictionaries with the BMI being a numeric value, and a single field for the day, month, and year, it is quite simple to do with predicates and KVC collection operators.

```
NSArray *distintDatesArray = [records valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.DayMonthYear"];

for( NSNumber *dayMonthYearValue in distintDatesArray )
{
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DayMonthYear = %@", dayMonthYearValue ]];

    NSArray *filteredRecords = [records filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

    NSNumber *avgBMI = [filteredRecords valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.BMI"];

    NSLog( @"Avg BMI on %@: %@", dayMonthYearValue, avgBMI );

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Since the data coming from an API, for now I'll stay with the current format. For the time being, this format is better when it comes to huge data sets.